# How to pass a kendo ui grid parameter in viewbag to action

Tags: parameters, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, viewbag

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SW.CRM.WebKendoUI.Models.ServiceOrderViewModel>()
      .Name("OrderManegementGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(e => e.Id).Title("订单编号").Visible(false);
          columns.Bound(e => e.ReservationNumber).Visible(false);
          columns.Bound(e => e.ServiceName).Title("服务名称");
          columns.Bound(e => e.FullName).Title("联系人");
          columns.Bound(e => e.MobileNumber).Title("手机号");
          columns.Bound(e => e.NumberPlate).Title("车牌号");
          columns.Bound(e => e.OrderReserveDatetime).Title("预约服务时间").Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}");
          columns.Bound(e => e.IsCanceled).Title("是否取消");
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar =>
      {
          toolbar.Save();
      }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))

      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
         .Ajax()
         .Batch(true)
         .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
         .Update("SaveOrderItems", "Orders")
         .Read(read => read.Action("GetOrderItems", "Orders", new {Id =@(ViewBag.VehicleModel) }))
      )
    )
```

I want to pass the value in viewBag to controller by new {Id =@(ViewBag.VehicleModel) },but it doesn't work.Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `Id` like this,

```
 .Read(read => read.Action("GetOrderItems", "Orders", new { @Id = ViewBag.VehicleModel }))
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult GetOrderItems([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,string Id)
 {

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I try another way and it also works. .Read(read => read.Action("GetOrderItems", "Orders", new { Id = @ViewBag.OrderReserveId}))